# Is it possible to build a vector at static compile time from different source files?

Tags: c++

I would like to cache jni class id's in the jniOnLoad method. Ultimately this process will work as follows:

```
for each class name in my list, call env->FindClass
```

As a developer I would prefer to not have to add a class name to a central static vector located outside of my class. Instead, I would like to keep registration with this collection within the file I am editing. For example

```
JNIUtility.h
void appendClassName(std::string &className); // append name to mClassNameVector

JNIUtility.cpp
vector<string> mClassNameVector;
void jniOnLoad()
  // iterate over all items in mClassNameVector and obtain the class id's

...

NewClass.cpp
  appendClassName("com/my/path/NewClass");
```

My question is, can I push_back onto mClassNameVector at static compile time? If so, how?

Comment: You cannot push_back at compile time, what exactly are the requirements for your problem

Comment: You cannot 'call' `push_back` at compile time. The best you can do is use a vector initializer list. What you are trying to do is ultimately not possible. You can only specify an initializer list in one place; spreading it across compilation units will not work. See [this](http://ignoringthevoices.blogspot.de/2011/11/c11-initializer-lists-and-range-for.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't construct your `std::vector<std::string>` at compile- or link-time. However, you can build it during static initialization. You can have a constructor of a global object call something on another global object. For example, you can do something like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> mClassNameVector;
static bool dummy = []{ mClassNameVector.push_back("some string"); return true; };
```

Once you move the registration to a different translation unit there are, however, two problems:

1. The order of construction of global objects is undefined across translation units (within a translation unit it is simply top to bottom). To avoid issues with calling `push_back()` on the not, yet, constructed vector, you'd just wrap the object into a function:

   ```
   std::vector<std::string>& mClassNameVector() {
       static std::vector<std::string> rc;
       return rc;
   }
   static bool dummy = []{ mClassNameVector().push_back("some string"); return true; };
   ```

   Since `static` function local variables are constructed when the function is called for the first time, this approach guarantees that the `mClassNameVector()` is constructed before it is accessed. Note, that the construction is not thread-safe in C++03. However, it is thread-safe in C++ (as of the 2011 revision): Only one thread will initialize `rc`. Any other thread entering the function while `rc` is being constructed will block.
2. The other potential problem is that your classes may not be referenced from anywhere and, as a result, the file containing the registration variable(s) may not be included into the final executable. Especially when implementing classes in a library and hoping that they would register themselves that tends to fail. Also, when the object files are build in a way which puts different entities into separate sections, there is a chance that the registration variables are not linked into the executable. Normally, it works explicitly linking the object files, however. Putting the object files into a library generally doesn't work unless each file contains a symbol which is referenced from somewhere.